# Dynamically change the content of the tooltip in kendoui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I have a drag and drop functionality. When the `element` is dragging, I want to dynamically
set the position of the element and display that in the `tooltip`. How can i able to do this
using kendoui.

I have defined like:

```
<div id='drag'><p>Drag me</p></div>
```

I have defined the tooltip like:

```
$("#drag").kendoToolTip({
   position:"top",
   content: "Initial"
});
```

Thne for dragging

```
 $("#drag").draggable({
   drag: function(){
       $("#drag").data("kendoToolTip").content("Dragging");
    },
   stop: function(){
      $("#drag").data("kendoToolTip").content("Drag stopped");
    } 
 });
```

And i want to show the tool tip on the `div` continuously on `dragging`.
How can i do that
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this one friend,

```
 $("#drag").data("kendoTooltip").options.content = "set content here...";

 $("#drag").data("kendoTooltip").refresh();
```

Comment: How you prevent tooltip from blinking? Or you don't even care about it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work if the content is loaded with AJAX...
Is there a solution?